# Bind gRPC service to localhost in Java

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I have a gRPC service which I would just like to bind just to the localhost address. However, I don't see a way to do that in Java. Instead it will bind to all addresses.

Here is how I create my service now:

```
server = ServerBuilder.forPort(config.port())
                      .addService(new GRPCServiceImpl(serviceParams))
                      .build()
                      .start();
LOG.info("Server started, listening on " + config.port());
```

There doesn't seem to be an API exposed on [ServerBuilder](http://www.grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ServerBuilder.html) or [Server](http://www.grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/Server.html) which allows specifying the address or network interface. Whereas the C++ API has [AddListentingPort](http://www.grpc.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_server_builder.html#acc75463f5d82b7774a83a4073d904f90).

So is there a way in Java to restrict which IP or interface the service listens on?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this by picking a more specific ServerBuilder, such as the NettyServerBuilder:

```
NettyServerBuilder.forAddress(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", config.port()))
    .addService(new GRPCServiceImpl(serviceParams))
    .build()
    .start();
```

Comment: ask as a question and i will answer it.